# Is it possible to terminate a SharePoint workflow via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, powershell, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I want to batch terminate workflows by clicking a custom button in the ribbon that (with JavaScript) grabs the selected items in the list by ID.  Can I terminate workflows in JavaScript?

Alternatively, I made a PowerShell script that can terminate all running workflows by item ID.  What's the best way to send the selected item data from JavaScript to a PowerShell script or to make them talk at all (obviously client/server related issues)?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean SharePoint ribbon - so your custom button is on SharePoint page you can create webservice with method which takes item ID as parameter. Method would terminate all running WFs through object model (code would be very simillar to one you wrote in PS script). Webservice must be deployed in SharePoint.

Then you can call webservice in javascript.

Described scenario is possible only if javascript and webservice is on same SharePoint application so you dont have to deal with authentication.

Check this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1231/ASP-NET-Web-Service). It describes how to create webservice and how to call it from javascript.